# How do I stop VSCode from searching for references in my virtual environments?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

The "Find all references" search takes forever.
[image]

When it finishes I see that VSCode searched for references in my virtual environments `.venv` and `.venvlinux`, even though I listed it under my "Files: Exclude" and "Files: Watcher Exclude" settings

[image]

[image]

My json.settings file looks like this

```
{
    "files.exclude": {
        "**/.git": true,
        "**/.svn": true,
        "**/.hg": true,
        "**/CVS": true,
        "**/.DS_Store": true,
        "**/Thumbs.db": true,
        "**/.venv": true,
        "**/.venvlinux": true
      },

      "files.watcherExclude": {
        "**/.git/objects/**": true,
        "**/.git/subtree-cache/**": true,
        "**/node_modules/*/**": true,
        "**/.hg/store/**": true,
        "**/.venv/**": true,
        "**/.venvlinux/**": true
      },
}
```

How do I stop VSCode from searching for references in my virtual environments?

Comment: Have you tried replacing `"**/.venvlinux/**"` with `"**/.venvlinux/"`?

Answer (score 3):

This problem seems to be linked to [Github Issue #6436 of vscode-remote-release](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-remote-release/issues/6436), which was already covered by [Github Issue #137872 of VSCode](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/137872).

Based on that discussion, it looks like this is an ongoing problem, and further help will probably come from commenting on that issue or opening your own and referencing it.

Answer (score 1):

I had this same issue. I had to add the pattern to my `Search.exclude` settings, instead of the `Files.exclude` settings.